# Deploying a react Application with NodeJS and express to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a web app that uses Express backend and React frontend. The heroku-postbuild script in my package.json is as follows:

```
 "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
```

When I `git push heroku master` all seems to be fine until I get:

"Failed at the honeyman-designs@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script."

this is the script:

```
 "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon --watch backend --exec babel-node backend/server.js",
     "build": "del -rf dist && babel backend -d dist",
     "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
   },
```

The script inside frontend is:

```
 "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
```

I'm using Windows 10 as my OS.

My Procfile contains:

```
 web: node dist/server.js
```

I'm not too sure what I'm doing to get this error if anybody can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: `npm run build && cd frontend && npm install && npm run build`: Wait, how? You can't do `npm run build` on the top of front end right? So does this mean, you have a `package.json` in the main directory with `build` script and there's another same thing inside `frontend` directory too? How's your folder structure looking?

Comment: Yes I have two package.json files. One in the main directory and the second is in the frontend directory

Comment: Okay, does it have a build script too in the main directory? Can you show us both `package.json` files, please?

Comment: yes, this is the one in the main directory ("build": "del -rf dist && babel backend -d dist",) and this is the one inside the frontend ("build": "react-scripts build",) I've updated to include both scripts

Comment: You can check my project, it has a working React + ExpressJS deployment https://github.com/KiraLT/torrent-stream-server. You can even test with Deploy to Heroku button